# error in unwind command "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'p': expected whitespace"

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

While loading data from csv file to neo4j, I am using below cypher query.

```
Load csv  from 
   "file:///resume" AS row 
FIELDTERMINATOR 
   '\u0001'
WITH 
   row, split(row[4], "|") AS pskills ,
   split(row[5], "|")  As frameworks,
   split(row[6], "|") As databases,
  UNWIND 
     pskills AS lang 
  UNWIND 
     frameworks AS fw
  UNWIND 
     databases As db
  MERGE 
   (p1:Person {name: row[1],id:row[0]}) 
  MERGE 
    (p2:Skill:language {name: lang}) 
  MERGE 
    (p3:Skill:framework {name: fw}) 
  MERGE 
    (p4:Skill:database {name: db}) 
  MERGE 
    (p1)-[:SKILLED_IN]->(p2)
 MERGE 
    (p1)-[:SKILLED_IN]->(p3)
 MERGE 
    (p1)-[:SKILLED_IN]->(p4);
```

which is giving error:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'p': expected
>   whitespace, comment, '{', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a
>   relationship pattern, '(', '.', '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS,
>   IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', '~', "<>", "!=", '<', '>',
>   "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, AS, ',', ORDER, SKIP, LIMIT, WHERE, FROM
>   GRAPH, CONSTRUCT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE
>   UNIQUE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN,
>   UNION, ';' or end of input (line 5, column 10 (offset: 189)) "  UNWIND
>   pskills AS lang "

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra `comma(,)` before first `UNWIND`

Comment: Load csv  from  "file:///resume" AS row 
FIELDTERMINATOR  '\u0001'
WITH row, split(row[4], "|") AS pskills ,
  split(row[5], "|")  As frameworks,
   split(row[6], "|") As databases
  UNWIND 
     pskills AS lang 
  UNWIND 
     frameworks AS fw
  UNWIND 
     databases As db
  MERGE 
   (p1:Person {name: row[1],id:row[0]}) 
  MERGE 
    (p2:Skill:language {name: lang}) 
  MERGE 
    (p3:Skill:framework {name: fw}) 
  MERGE 
    (p4:Skill:database {name: db}) 
  MERGE 
    (p1)-[:SKILLED_IN]->(p2)
 MERGE 
    (p1)-[:SKILLED_IN]->(p3)
 MERGE 
    (p1)-[:SKILLED_IN]->(p4);